# One or multiple use cases (UML)

Tags: uml, analysis, use-case

I'm beginning software Analysis and Design. In my software, an actor can only read or delete an item (but not edit it). Should i define this as a single use-case (read or delete an item) or as two separate use cases (a use case for read an item and a different use case for delete an item) ? 
Thank you for your anwswers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say two use cases, one for each. A bit more bloated, but as I've dealt with changing specs that had details that weren't included "because it's obvious", I'm prefer over-communication rather than the alternative.

By defining it as two use cases, it cuts any ambiguety as to whether there are any more things hidden in the fine print, plus, i like a spec that practically states "These two, and only these two".

I hope that makes sense. I'm by far no authority on UML, but someone who's been on the receiving-end of them for ages.